# OOP PHP - correct way to use a parent obj instance from children and other classes

Tags: php, oop

I have this code:

```
class MyObj {
    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;

    function __construct() {
        $this->var1 = FALSE;
        $this->var2 = FALSE;
        $this->var3 = 0;
    }

    function getVar1() {
        return $this->var1;
    }
    function getVar2() {
        return $this->var2;
    }
    function getVar3() {
        return $this->var3;
    }

    function setVar1($var1) {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
    }
    function setVar2($var2) {
        $this->var2 = $var2;
    }
    function setVar3($var3) {
        $this->var3 = $var3;
    }
}

class AA {
    // ...
}

class A extends AA {
    public $myobj;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->myobj = new MyObj();
    }
    public function getMyObj() {
        return $this->myobj;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->fun1();
    }
    private function fun1() {
        $this->myobj->setVar1(TRUE);
    }
}
class C extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->fun2();
    }
    private function fun2() {
        $this->myobj->setVar2(TRUE);
    }
}

class OtherClass extends AA {
    public function __construct() {
        $B = new B();
        $C = new C();
        $C->getMyObj()->setVar3(5);

        var_dump ( $C->getMyObj()->getVar1() ); // false
        var_dump ( $C->getMyObj()->getVar2() ); // true
        var_dump ( $C->getMyObj()->getVar3() ); // 5

        echo "<br/><br/>";

        var_dump ( $B->getMyObj()->getVar1() ); // NULL 
        var_dump ( $B->getMyObj()->getVar2() ); // false 
        var_dump ( $B->getMyObj()->getVar3() ); // 0
    }
}

new OtherClass();
```

the problem is that I need a way to access `$this->myobj` var from `OtherClass` in order to get all updates from all the `set()` functions.
So I'd expect the following result in `OtherClass` constructor:

```
var_dump ( $C->getMyObj()->getVar1() ); // true
var_dump ( $C->getMyObj()->getVar2() ); // true
var_dump ( $C->getMyObj()->getVar3() ); // 5
```

I don't know either whether using that `MyObj` class with `$C->getMyObj()` is a good way to track the updates from the various class instances (`B`, `C`, `OtherClass`).
If not I accept any tip.

Thanks

Comment: `$this->myobj` is totally unrelated to the objects in `$B` and `$C`.

Comment: The constructors for `B` and `C` have no effect on the `OtherClass` object.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your help. So do you have any idea about how to solve the problem and get that result?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. What do the `B` and `C` objects have to do with `OtherClass`? Are you trying to get their constructors to modify the parts of this object's parent class that they have in common?

Comment: The fact that they all have `MyObj` as a superclass doesn't really make them related that way. They're still completely unrelated objects.

Comment: @Barmar, yes that's what I'm trying to do. In `OtherClass`, `B`, `C` classes I need to get the always updated value of `$myobj` var (defined in `A`). That way the result of `var_dump ( $C->getMyObj()->getVar1() ); ...` etc... will be as I expect as above.

Comment: Then all those classes should be in the inheritance chain of `OtherClass`, and you should be invoking their constructors on the current object, not unrelated objects.

Comment: @Barmar, unfortunately I can't change that structure. Do you know any other way to do that just keeping that inheritance structure?

Comment: Are you initialize the other objects, copy their properties to the similar properties of `$this`.

Comment: @Barman, I'm sorry but I did not understand your tip. Could you please make an example? Thanks

Comment: `$this->setVar1($B->getvar1());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved the problem using the `singleton pattern`.

The problem was that, calling `parent::__construct();` from `B` and `C` does  always create a new instance of `$this->myobj` (`$this->myobj = new MyObj();`) so I was loosing my edits.

I edited the code like that:

```
class MyObj {

    private static $instance;

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;

    function __construct() {
        $this->var1 = FALSE;
        $this->var2 = FALSE;
        $this->var3 = 0;
    }

    function getVar1() {
        return $this->var1;
    }
    function getVar2() {
        return $this->var2;
    }
    function getVar3() {
        return $this->var3;
    }

    function setVar1($var1) {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
    }
    function setVar2($var2) {
        $this->var2 = $var2;
    }
    function setVar3($var3) {
        $this->var3 = $var3;
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if( !isset( self::$instance ) ){
            self::$instance = new MyObj();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

}

class AA {

}




class A extends AA {
    public function __construct() {

    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->fun1();
    }
    private function fun1() {
        $myobj = MyObj::getInstance();
        $myobj->setVar1(TRUE);
    }
}
class C extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->fun2();
    }
    private function fun2() {
        $myobj = MyObj::getInstance();
        $myobj->setVar2(TRUE);
    }
}

class OtherClass extends AA {
    public function __construct() {
        $myobj = MyObj::getInstance();
        $B = new B();
        $C = new C();
        $myobj->setVar3(5);

        var_dump ( $myobj->getVar1() ); // true
        var_dump ( $myobj->getVar2() ); // true
        var_dump ( $myobj->getVar3() ); // 5
    }
}

new OtherClass();
```